# Highcharts treegraph chart zooming is not working (using highcharts version 11.1.0 with highcharts-react-officialversion 3.2.1)

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

From highcharts version 11, mouseWheel zooming is supposed to work out of the box when using highcharts/highstock, but in my case , with a treegraph serie type, it doesn't, can anyone help with this please, thank's in advance.

I even tried  this config
zooming: {
enabled: true,
type: 'xy',
mouseWheel: {
enabled: true,
},
},

defined inside the chart object inside the chart options but the zooming still not working.

Comment: Hi @Oussama Abdelwahed, Zooming is not supported by the treegraph series. Related feature request: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/19780